# Not able to display video in PHP

Tags: php, html, video

On my site, users are able to upload videos.
And I am storing that videos in a folder and their path in the mysql database.

I want to retrieve that videos from the folder and get display on the page.
That folder also contains images.
I am showing that images also. 
Images are getting displayed. And videos only play audio, and not the video. And also, I have only two videos in my database and one image. Then also 3 video files and 3 image are getting display, from which two images are displayed with alternate text.

Following is the code I tried in PHP:

```
if ($db_found) 
{
    $query ="SELECT * FROM `files`";        
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db_handle);   
    echo "<div class='product'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $src=$row['File'];
        echo "<img src='$src' height='200' width='200' alt='Image not Found'/>";
        echo "<video width='200' height='200' autoplay controls>
              <source src='$src' type='video/mp4'>
              </video>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: how do you know your videos are encoded properly?

Comment: You're using the **SAME** src for the video and image. Exactly how do you expect `<source src="kittens.jpg">` to work? images aren't videos.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an issue with php. It is an issue with your browser's support of the html5 video tag, or with the files themselves, or with the server on which the videos are stored.

Comment: then can you tell me that how can i display all images and videos which are stored in the same folder.

Comment: @marc - hilarious! I didn't even notice that. But still, when they're not jpgs, he is getting audio only. I've never encountered this myself unless the video is encoded incorrectly.

Comment: You know, it just occurred to me - what are the exact file types for your videos? If someone uploads an ogv or mov file are you still assigning the type as video/mp4?

Comment: no the videos files are mp4 only.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont know how to encode the video or how to check encode. I am doing this first time and i am a new learner to programming. so can anyone help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check which are videos and which are images using something like:

```
 $src=$row['File'];

        if (preg_match("/\.jpg$/i",$src)){

            echo "<img src='$src' height='200' width='200' alt='Image not Found'/>";

        }else{

             echo "<video width='200' height='200' autoplay controls> <source src='$src' type='video/mp4'> </video>";

        }
```

**Edit**

Oh and please stop using the deprecated [mysql functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Choose a more modern method of connecting to the db

Comment: thanks it worked but not fully. it plays only audio, not video.

Comment: as others have said, check the video encoding, you can test this by opening the video file in an html5 browser directly

Answer (score 0):

You really should add (at the very least) some way to separate your videos and images. For example, a second column in your `files` table that tells you if the file in question is a video or image.

Then you can simply do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `filetype` == 1
```

Where 1 = image, 2 = video, etc.

Then you can simply process that array as you please:

```
<?php
foreach($images as $image) { ?>
    <img src='<?= $image["src" ?>' alt=''>
<?php } ?>
```

And

```
<?php
foreach($videos as $video) { ?>
  <video id="video" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="<?= $video["src"] ?>.mp4">
  </video>
<?php } ?>
```

Note: The fact that only audio is playing on your videos has NOTHING to do with your code.